Breaking strict aliasing when reinterpret_cast-ing pointer to an object vs directly casting the reference of the same object
There are multiple questions about the warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer might break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing], from when adding compiler options -Wstrict-aliasing=2 -fstrict-aliasing, and how to solve it.
For instance, the most upvoted answer to this Q states that,

(...) gcc assumes that your program will never access variables though pointers of different type.
This assumption is called strict-aliasing and allows the compiler to make some optimizations (...)

When attempting to rewrite (read cast) a struct as an array (for use in an external API), I found that the warning disapeared when adding an intermediate step of creating a pointer to said struct object, and casting that pointer instead.
I want to know if this is (not safe but) safer than directly casting the struct object's reference (which prompts the warning), or have I just conceiled what I'm doing from the compiler in such a way that the compiler doesn't see the danger and doesn't produce the warning? If it is safer, why? I don't really understand the actual difference.
If it matters, the reinterpret_cast-ed data is never accessed: it is stored/transported and reinterpret_cast-ed back again to the original struct before being used.
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

struct Container
{
    uint32_t x;
    uint32_t y;
};

// SomeApi could for instance have been (from <fcntl>),
// write(some_fd, data, size);
void SomeApi(uint32_t* data, size_t size)
{
    for (size_t i=0; i<size; i++)
        std::cout << (i==0?"{":", ") << static_cast<unsigned>(data[i]);
    std::cout << "}\n";
}

int main() {

    Container c{3,4};

    uint32_t* data = reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(&c);
    SomeApi(data, sizeof(c)/sizeof(uint32_t));
    // warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer might break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]

    Container* p_c = &c;
    uint32_t* p_data = reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(p_c);
    SomeApi(p_data, sizeof(c)/sizeof(uint32_t));
    // Seemingly without issues?

    return 0;
}


"safer" No it is absolutely not. Why would it ever be? "the reinterpret_cast-ed data is never accessed: it is stored/transported and reinterpret_cast-ed back again to the original struct before being used." I can't see any of it in the example code. Assuming your actual code is different, how can you get the data "stored/transported" without accessing it?

@n.m.couldbeanAI Thanks for the comment. «… why would it ever be»: because the warning goes away. The question is, does it go away because it is somehow safer (considering aliasing only), or does it go away because the compiler does no longer “see” what is going on?

@n.m.couldbeanAI … ok, “never accessed” might be a poor formulation. The ‘uint32_t’ array is written to a file. The file is later read into a buffer array before ‘reinterpret_cast’ back. It is a “save current state functionality” for scientific simulation going on for days. The struct is very big, but consists only of uint32_t members.

"I want to know if this is (not safe but) safer than directly casting the struct object's reference" - This is really strange to me; safe is not a gradual scale. Either something is safe (guaranteed) or it is not. If something is not guaranteed (safe) it is a bug in my opinion.

"The ‘uint32_t’ array is written to a file" So you cast it to char* or void* and presumably write accesses it as a char array. This is allowed. Why involve uint32_t in the middle then?

There is no difference, you have undefined behavior in the second loop iteration inside SomeApi when you do static_cast<unsigned>(data[i]) with i == 1 because data[i] will be the pointer one-past the object c.x which, as all one-past pointers, musn't be dereferenced, which data[i] however does.
Tricking the compiler's detection of the issue doesn't change anything about it.
Passing to write instead of SomeApi would be a different matter. Then you shouldn't doing any casting at all and the API is defined to access the underlying bytes of the object, not to access the object with a wrong type.

Thanks, this is all I needed to know. It was not clear to me whether the extra step actually made a difference, or if it just fools the compiler. I interpret “Tricking the compiler's detection of the issue doesn't change anything about it.”, that the extra step only conceals the issue, rather than fix anything.

@Wololo yes, indeed
